# Host Drupal site from Dev desktop to Acquia cloud - error

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop, acquia-cloud

I'm trying to host my Drupal site from Acquia desktop to Acquia cloud but I get the error - "Drush was unable to create site archive" . Any assistance would be appreciated. Also note, I am just starting to learn Drupal and have little to no programming experience. Full error message below:

```
Drush was unable to create site archive.
StdErr:php.exe "C:/Program Files (x86)/DevDesktop/tools/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php" --php=php.exe  --backend=2       [notice]
--verbose --root="C:/Users/Robert Kitchen/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8.4.4" --uri=default  sql-conf   --all 2>&1
Executing: bsdtar.exe  --exclude "drupal-8.4.4/sites" --dereference -cf "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar" drupal-8.4.4
Executing: bsdtar.exe  --dereference -rf "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar" drupal-8.4.4/sites/all
Executing: bsdtar.exe --dereference -rf "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar" drupal-8.4.4/sites/README.txt
Executing: bsdtar.exe --dereference -rf "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar" drupal-8.4.4/sites/sites.php
Executing: bsdtar.exe --dereference -rf "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar" drupal-8.4.4/sites/example.sites.php
Executing: bsdtar.exe --dereference -rf "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar" drupal-8.4.4/sites/development.services.yml
Executing: bsdtar.exe --dereference -rf "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar" drupal-8.4.4/sites/example.settings.local.php
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file="C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\dru8702.tmp" --database=newsite --host=127.0.0.1 --port=33067 --silent  < "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\dru86F1.tmp"
Calling system(mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\dru8761.tmp"  newsite --host=127.0.0.1 --port=33067 --no-autocommit --single-transaction --opt -Q  > "C:\\Users\\ROBERT~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/drush_tmp_1519595877_5a933165c1079/newsite.sql");
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line 1 (1064)
Database dump failed                                                                                             [error]
Executing: bsdtar.exe  --dereference -rf "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar" newsite.sql
php.exe "C:/Program Files (x86)/DevDesktop/tools/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php" --php=php.exe  --backend=2       [notice]
--verbose --root="C:/Users/Robert Kitchen/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8.4.4" --uri=default  core-status 2>&1
Executing: bsdtar.exe  --dereference -rf "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar" drupal-8.4.4/sites/default
Executing: bsdtar.exe --dereference -rf "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar" MANIFEST.ini
Executing: bsdtar.exe -tf "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar" drupal-8.4.4/sites/default/default.settings.php
Executing: gzip --no-name -f "C:\\Users\\Robert Kitchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/newsite.20180225_215755.tar"
Archive saved to C:\Users\Robert Kitchen\AppData\Local\Temp/acquia-drupal.tmp.tar.gz                                [ok]
Command dispatch complete                                                                                       [notice]
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue... same mysql error. Did you find a solution?